# Spinner doesn't show any text inside custom dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I have a spinner with a custom view. When using the spinner in fragment it was working well but when moving it to an activity it doesn't show any text or items in it.The other items in the dialog works well the problem is only in the spinner. I have debugged the code for hours but with no hope.

this is the java code :

```
   LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    final View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_subject_spinner, null);

    final AlertDialog alertDialogBuilderUserInput = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setView(view)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create();

    final EditText inputComment = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_value);
    TextView dialogTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
    Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.dialogSubjectsSpinner);
    dialogTitle.setText("إضافة منشور");
    inputComment.setHint("اكتب سؤالك هنا");

    ImageView closeIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.closeIcon);
    closeIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialogBuilderUserInput.dismiss();
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> subjectsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,R.layout.testactiv,R.array.preparatory_subjects_array_with_general_subjects_item){


        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = null;
            v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
            // If this is the selected item position
            if (position == selectedItem) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_white));

                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                // Set the text color of spinner item
                tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


            } else {
                // for other views
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
            return v;
        }
    };
    spinner.setAdapter(subjectsAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            selectedItem =  i;
            currentSubject = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

and this is the xml code of the spinner :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/dialogSubjectsSpinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_spinner"
    android:ems="10"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/writelessonname"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

and this is the code of the drawable :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item><layer-list>
    <item><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"
        >
        <corners
            android:radius="@dimen/_10sdp"
            />
        <solid
            android:color="#FFFF"
            />


        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/gray" />
        <padding
            android:left="@dimen/_15sdp"/>
    </shape></item>
    <item ><bitmap android:gravity="end|center"


        android:src="@drawable/spin" />
    </item>





</layer-list>


</item>
```

Comment: Did you try without overriding `getDropDownView` in your `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Moreover did you call `show()` to show `AlertDialog`?